# Heroku 404 error - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, http-status-code-404

I'm making a ruby on rails app and I'm always getting a 404 error every time I visit my page on Heroku. I have tested my code on a localhost server and everything works on there. I have also scaled the app with `ps:scale` and migrated the database with `db:migrate`. I've searched through many posts online, but nothing helped.

Heres my routes.rb file

http://pastebin.com/eWr0J8aH

Comment: What do you see in your log files?

Comment: What 404 error do you see? Is it the heroku 404? are you going to your root and getting 404? or are you trying to view a Glue?

Comment: Anywhere I go, I get a 404, the 404 I set in my project. The logs say something about an uninitialized constant WelcomeController

Comment: 1) And locally, you can visit the root page? 2) When you run `git status` what does it say?

Comment: I am getting a similar issue on my app. After running 'heroku restart' it runs fine for me.